# SQL Server extract first array element from JSON

Tags: sql-server-2016

I have json stored in one of the columns in SQL Server and I need to modify it to remove the square brackets from it. The format is as below. Can't seem to find a good way of doing it.

```
[ { "Message":"Info: this is some message here.", "Active":true } ]
```

One way is to do it using below query, but this query is very very slow and I need to run on a very large set of data.

```
select a.value
from dbo.testjson e
cross apply OPENJSON(e.jsontext) as a
where isjson(e.jsontext) = 1
```

The only other way I can think of is just doing string manipulation but it can be error prone. Could someone help with this?

Answer (score 10):

Ok, figured it out:

```sql
select 
    json_query(
        '[{"Message":"Info: this is some message here.","Active":true}]',
        '$[0]'
    )
```

This will return the inner message.

Comment: I was searching for ages before I found this gem '$[0]' to work with the first element of a JSON array.

Answer (score 2):

You should add the property name, in this case Message, in order to get only that part. Keep in mind that it's case sensitive. Something like;

```
 select json_value('[{"Message":"Info: this is some message here.","Active":true}]', '$[0].Message')
```